# Default Eclipse Theme for Android Development Spinners?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

The color of my Spinner widgets change from phone to phone based on there settings,I would like to keep them the same between all phones and I would like to have it be the default eclipse uses in its emulators the color is silverish.  Can you please let me know how to apply this specific theme to my Spinner in xml.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Android fragmentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the images used in for the spinner from the android source code: spinner_press.9.png, spinner_select.9.png, spinner_normal.9.png then create selector using those.
this is the default selector:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_press" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_select" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: These pngs, when added offcourse, all look awkward and dont look like Spinners

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a theme. Just apply a background of your choice to the spinner, as with any other View.

If you want to have different backgrounds you can use a  (See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for more info)

For an example of an implementation, nothing better than the android source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/res/res/drawable/spinner_background.xml

You can get the actual 9-patch files from there also (and choose which version you would like to use).

Comment: How do I find the background used by default for the spinner in the Eclipse/Android-Emulator?

Comment: I guess Eclipse uses the images on the SDK? You have the png files on the SDK/platforms/API_LEVEL/data/res/drawable-XXX/

Comment: I went there and found the files however, they were the same as the link you had provided and they dont look like spinners.  Thanks for the above help though any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean they don't look like spinners? Did you even try the solutions posted before replying? Those are the files used by android to make the spinner backgrounds. Please take a look at the dev guide if you have questions about the 9-patch files: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch